# CS0433 The type 'SerializableAttribute' exists in both 'Autofac, Version=4.0.1.0' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0'

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

I am getting the above error trying to build a dotnetcore 2.0 web application.

> CS0433    The type 'SerializableAttribute' exists in both 'Autofac, Version=4.0.1.0' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0'

I suspect it might be a bug, any pointers on how to overcome the issue would be greatly appreciated.

I am using:
**Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.2.1"**

My project file is pretty simple.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>crypto.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.7</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Documentation.Analyser" Version="1.0.6538.15147" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="7.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive.Core" Version="4.0.0-preview00001" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.0.1-dev-00795" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspnetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="CryptoBadger.db">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="logs\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: It is not a "dotnetcore 2.0 web application".  You are on the bleeding edge with the beta version of 2.1.  Blood loss is expected, consider 2.0 to simplify your life.

Comment: It appears you double-filed this here and [as an issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/issues/29). The answer is on the issue. It would help the community if you'd try just one place first to avoid duplicate effort.